# How to use a Boolean values (true, false) from xml in as3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am loading some data from xml file to flash project as a values.. the numbers are working well but the Boolean values (true, false) aren't working!

xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SETTINGS>
<SET VALUE="2">Size</SET>
<SET VALUE="false">Lock</SET>
</SETTINGS>
```

as3 code:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    size_ns.value = myXML.SET[0].@VALUE;
    lock_cb.selected = myXML.SET[1].@VALUE;
    trace(myXML.SET[1].@VALUE);
};
```

output: false

but the lock_cb.selected still true!
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how output could be "false" when in the XML file you have it set to "true"?

Comment: sorry it's false I've changed it..

Answer (score 0):

The string `false` evaluates to Boolean true, you can convert it to a Boolean by comparing it to the string `true`.

Try

```
lock_cb.selected = myXML.SET[1].@VALUE === 'true';
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I can't set the value inside the flash file.. it should be a setting file for the user!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having issues with [XML type conversion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6d.html). Keep in mind that all E4X queries are going to return `XML` or `XMLList` objects, and can only be implicitly converted to `Strings`. In other words, the `VALUE` is the string `"false"` not the boolean `false`.

However, you can convert it to a boolean by using a comparison:

```
var value:Boolean = myXML.SET[1].@VALUE == true;
```

This works because [the `==` operator will convert both values to strings when one operand is an XML attribute](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality), and so `"true" == "true"` becomes `true`, while `"false" == "true"` becomes `false`. In other words it's the same as this:

```
var value:Boolean = myXML.SET[1].@VALUE == "true";
```

The reason the numbers work is because assigning a `String` to a `Number` will implicitly parse the string into a number.

Yes, the implicit casting can make things confusing.

As a final note, this may be beyond what you can or want to do right now, but [JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) supports boolean, numbers, and null, so you don't have this same problem with it.

Comment: JSON is an alternative data format. It's newer than XML and has gained a lot of popularity due to its simplicity. Flash supports native JSON parsing and encoding, similar to XML (though it doesn't have the E4X query syntax). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Comment: got it thanks a lot, i think it's a long story i mean the JSON , I have to figure  it out but not now :P

Comment: JSON takes 5 minutes to figure